# make query with variable in mysql

Tags: mysql

Could anyone help me with this?

Server version: 5.5.34-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

```
mysql> SET @MY_CURRENT_DATE = CAST( CONCAT( CURDATE(), ' 00:00:00' ) AS DATETIME );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET @MY_WEEKDAY = WEEKDAY( NOW() );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT DATE_SUB( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL @MY_WEEKDAY + 14 DAY ), DATE_SUB( @MY_WEEKDAY + 8 DAY );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAY )' at line 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have wrongly used `Date_sub` function. It needs a `date` value as first parameter, where as you input an `int` (weekday) value and an insufficient number of input parameters. And hence is the error.

```
-- this is wrong
DATE_SUB( @MY_WEEKDAY + 8 DAY ) 

-- this is right
DATE_SUB( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL @MY_WEEKDAY + 14 DAY )

-- this is corrected to be right
DATE_SUB( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL @MY_WEEKDAY + 8 DAY )
```

**Syntax**:

- [DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).
- [DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub).

Comment: thank you for response, working right now:
`SELECT DATE_SUB( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL @MY_WEEKDAY + 14 DAY ), DATE_SUB( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL @MY_WEEKDAY + 8 DAY );`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're getting a syntax error on the DAY area...so it should have to do with something in that general vicinity.

Looking at what you're trying to do, and what function you're using. I can say:

Its cause you're using `DATE_SUB` and trying to add...why not use `DATE_ADD` plus you're missing the `INTERVAL` part of your second aggregate. Forgetting words,and not using the function appropriately will result in MySQL not knowing what you're trying to do. The first agg uses appropriate syntax, the second one doesn't. But it should look roughly like:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE_ADD( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL (@MY_WEEKDAY + 14 DAY )), ____________;
```

It would more than likely be something like:

```
DATE_SUB( @MY_WEEKDAY, INTERVAL 8 DAY)
```

but again, not sure what you're trying here...

Comment: Thank you for your help, but unfortunately this still fail
`SELECT DATE_ADD( @MY_CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL ( @MY_WEEKDAY + 14 DAY ) ), DATE_ADD( @MY_WEEKDAY, INTERVAL + 8 DAY );
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DAY ) ), DATE_ADD( @MY_WEEKDAY, INTERVAL + 8 DAY )' at line 1`